# Docker windows 10pro git, postgres - alpine. Не подключается к тестовой базе, git clone project (ssh-key)

Tags: windows, postgresql, git, docker, git-clone

**Приветствую!** Нужна ваша помощь.
Потратил много часов на разборку docker, конкретно для Windows 10 (это ад, но нужна именно windows).

Нужен образ для web:

```
-Php 7.2-fpm-alpine
-Nginx:alpine
-Postgres10.1-alpine
-Composer
-Node10.2-alpine
-Git

Загружал необходимый софт, клонировал проект, записывал базу, создавал команды по composer (composer install, update) и node (npm install, update).
```

Все это на windows10pro->alpine.
Nginx + php + composer + node уже работает, остальное нет.

Имеется проблема с docker - git clone (.ssh-key), postgres (db:postgres) os alpine. Если быть точным с правами для git и default база не подключается.

Суть ошибки:

Git:
Права выставлял разными путями - chmod, создавал docker-entrypoint.sh, volume на .ssh. В общем ничего не помогает. Проект не клонирует, ssh совпадает host(win10)/docker(alpine)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Postgres:
Не создается default db, хотя environment прописан верно. Прописывал и в самом Dockerfile, но к успеху не привело. Нужно чтобы база хранилась у меня и на контейнере при запуске.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой docker-composer:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
nginx:
    build: ./docker
    restart: always
    networks:
        - backend
    volumes:
        - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - ./logs-nginx:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    links:
        - php

php:
    build: ./docker/php
    restart: always
    networks:
        - backend
    links:
        - node
        - postgres
    volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}

postgres:
    build: ./docker/postgres
    networks:
        - backend
    restart: always
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        - PGDATA=/tmp
    ports:
        - 5433:5432        
    volumes:
        - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

composer:
    image: composer
    volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install

node:
    build: ./docker/node
    user: node
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    environment:
       - NODE_ENV=production
    networks:
       - backend
    volumes:
       - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:/home/node/app
    expose:
       - "8081"

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

**Мой dockerfile php:**

```
   FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

   USER root

   #COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
   #RUN chmod +x /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
   #ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

   RUN apk --update add ca-certificates \
       && apk add -U \
       # Packages ./.   git \
       openssh \    # Clean up
       && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

   VOLUME /var/www   VOLUME /root/.ssh

   # Clone a repository (my website in this case) git clone git@github.com:user/rep
```

---

Dockerfile postgres:

```
   FROM postgres:10.1-alpine

   VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

   EXPOSE 5432
```

Comment: Лучше бы указали, чем указывать на неправильно оформление.Лишь бы по умничать